# Frobenius acting by autoequivalence on $\text{Isoc}(X/K)$

Tags: nt.number-theory, arithmetic-geometry, connections, crystals

Let $X_k$ be a smooth quasiprojective scheme over a finite field $k$. Let $X_K$ be a smooth lift of $X_k$ to the fraction field of the Witt ring of $k$, which I denote by $K$.

In various papers I read that pullback by Frobenius induces an equivalence of categories between $Isoc(X_k/K)$ and itself.

Does pulling back by Frobenius also act by an autoequivalence on the category of algebraic vector bundles with an integrable connection on $X_K$? I imagine there should be a failure in the case when $X_k$ is not proper, but I am not sure why.